# Acer touch screen laptop using windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Cracked screen renders touch screen partially working on laptop, wanted to add Acer UT220HQL touch screen monitor and use its touch screen as main monitor.

I set the Acer touch screen as the main monitor, but cannot get the touch function to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed the required [drivers](https://acer-us.com/4988_3_UT220HQL/) for this touch screen?  Typically it wouldn't have a driver, but it also takes input, and input devices always need a driver.  Keyboards/Mice happen to use the standard I/O/USB driver but that is outside the scope of this question.